# Deserialize password string in json to Guarded String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I have a post rest api in spring boot. I am sending the password string in json payload for this api. While deserializing using jackson, I am using the String field in Request Dto class. Since, it is not secure I would like to know if there is way to deserialize the password string in json to guarded string implementation.
Guarded String Url : https://docs.oracle.com/html/E28160_01/org/identityconnectors/common/security/GuardedString.html

Or is. there a way to deserialize the string json to char array using jackson annotations.

Comment: If you know that the path is `https` protected, you can send secrets without fear of interception.  But it is highly desirable to use an authentication mechanism that does not rely on shared secrets.

Comment: I do not have problem with that, the problem is while deserializing the json password string, I want to deserialize as char array or guarded string.